# Why is this true? (uniform distributions)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

> If $Z=F(X)$, then $Z$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

I understand the proof using functions, but visually it doesn't make sense.

If $X$ is a normal distribution, then its cdf $F(X)$ looks like:

[image]

If we take $Z=F(X)$, $Z$ does not look like a uniform distribution (no flat top, its curved here). What am I missing?

Comment: Graph of $F^{-1}(z)$ is what you need.

Comment: My guess is that you are confusing the two concepts: the *random variable* $Z=F(X)$ and the *graph of the function* $z = F(x)$.

Comment: The graph shows that the mode of $X$ at $0$ becomes spread out around $1/2$ while the tails of $X$ become bunched up near $0, 1$.  That makes sense to me.

Comment: I still don't understand..... It says $Z=F(X)$, meaning $Z$ is the function for the line in the above image when graphed. That is not the shape of a uniform distribution.

Comment: To clear doubt, we need to know how the random variables are defined in the textbook you are studying with. But the standard definition is that a random variable $X$ is a (measurable) real-valued function on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Then, if you are given a (Borel-measurable) function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, you can transform $X$ to another random variable $Z=g(X)$ defined by $$Z:\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\qquad Z(\omega)=g(X(\omega))\quad\text{for all}\quad\omega\in\Omega.$$ In particular, $Z=F(X)$ in your example is NOT a function on $\mathbb{R}$ in general.

Comment: In particular, the horizontal axis for the graph of $F(\cdot)$ does not directly correspond to anything about the random variable $X$, hence the shape of the graph of $F(\cdot)$ does not directly teach us the behavior of the transformed random variable $F(X)$. (It is quite analogous to the situation where the behavior of the composition $f \circ g$ cannot be discussed in detail if we only know $f$ but not $g$.)

Comment: You say $Z=F(X)$. Consider a particular case such as $\mathbb P(Z \le 0.6)$.  This is $\mathbb P(F(X) \le 0.6)$, and that is $0.6$, at least if $X$ has a continuous cumulative distribution function, since the probability that $X$ is small enough to have $F(X) \le 0.6$ is precisely $0.6$ by the definition of $F(X)$.  Similarly for all $z \in (0,1)$ when you consider $\mathbb P(Z \le z)$, and this means $Z=F(X)$ is uniformly distributed at least on $(0,1)$.  And clearly $\mathbb P(F(X) \le 0)=0$ and $\mathbb P(F(X) \le 1)=1$, so $Z=F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: In your diagram, you want $F(x)$ to be on the $x$ axis and $\mathbb P(F(X)\le F(x))$ on the $y$ axis.  For $0<F(x)<1$ this will give you the diagonal straight line associated with the CDF of a uniform distribution

Comment: This is an important concept for both theoretical and applied statistics. Please don't leave this topic without beginning to understand it. I hope examples in my Answer are helpful.

Comment: Comment by @DannyPakKeungChan to my Answer really belongs here. For this proposition to be true $X$ must be a continuous random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you transform a random sample by the (continuous) CDF of its population, it becomes standard uniform.**

First, I find the notation to be unfortunate and it may be
confusing you. Let's say $U = F_X(X) \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ for a continuous random variable $X.$

Second, let's investigate a couple of specific examples.

*Example 1:*
Suppose $X = \mathsf{Beta}(2,2),$ with $f_X(x) = 6x(1-x),$ for $0<x<1,$ a parabola. Also,
$F_X(x) = 3x^2 - 2x^3.$

We can use R statistical software to sample $n=500$ observations in vector `x` from $\mathsf{Beta}(2,2).$
in R, the density is denoted `dbeta` and the CDF is denoted `pbeta` (each with appropriate parameters).

```
set.seed(721)
x = rbeta(500, 2, 2)
u = pbeta(x, 2, 2)
```

The expression for `u` amounts to $u =3x^2 - 2x^3.$

A histogram (blue) provides a crude estimate of
the corresponding density function (red), and an empirical CDF (ECDF) plot provides an estimate of the corresponding CDF.

[image]

An ECDF uses actual data, while a histogram uses
binned data (with some loss of information). So
ECDFs are ordinarily better estimates of CDFs, than
are histograms estimates of densities. The number
of observations $n = 500$ is a compromise to get
histograms that are not too rough, while getting
an ECDF that can (barely) be distinguished from its
corresponding CDF.

As you suspected, the 'action' takes place in the ECDF plot. Below we show how nine particular
points in `x` (out 0f 500) get transformed to appropriate values in 'u'.

[image]

*Example 2:* Here is a similar example in which we transform 1000 points 'x' from the distribution \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=15) to standard uniform by using the CDF of this normal distribution.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rnorm(500, 100, 15)
u = pnorm(x, 100, 15)
```

[image]

*Note:* In case you are interested in R code
for the figures, here is the code for the first two. (The third uses minor modifications of the first.)

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
hdr1 = "BETA(2,2): Histogram and Density"
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr1)
 curve(dbeta(x,2,2), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
hdr2 = "BETA(2,2), ECDF and CDF"
plot(ecdf(x), col="blue", lty="dashed", main=hdr2)
 curve(pbeta(x,2,2), add=T, col="red")
 hdr3 = "UNIF(0,1): Histogram and Density"
 hist(u, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr3)
  curve(dunif(x), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

sx = sort(x);  X = sx[seq(50,450, by=50)]
U = pbeta(X, 2,2)
plot(ecdf(x), col="blue", main="ECDF or Beta Sample")
for(i in 1:9) {
 lines(c(-.2, X[i], X[i]), c(U[i],U[i], 0), col="green2")
 }
```

[The R procedure `curve` requires the argument `x`, regardless of what is being plotted.]

Comment: The conclusion is false unless $F$ is continuous. For example, consider the case of constant random variable $X$. This condition should be stated explicitly and cannot be omitted.

Comment: Obviously correct. Making an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $F$ is the cumulative distribution function associated to the given random variable $X$.

In general, the claim that $Z = F\circ X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ is false, unless we impose condition on $F$ (we require that $F$ is continuous).

The following is an obvious counter-example:
Let $X$ be a constant random variable $X=0$.
Then $F(x) = 0$ if $x<0$ and $F(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$.
In this case $F\circ X$ can only take values 0 or 1,
so $F\circ X$ cannot be uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.